# Closed curve of a given given

Tags: calculus

How to check if the given function is closed. If so, what are those points?
Could you please help provide a hint on how to proceed with this.
$y^2+x^2+\frac {x^4}{2}=2c^2$
I am attempting to find the solution by writing y in terms of x however ai am bothered about the constant $c^2$

Comment: Hello Aruha welcome here , maybe there is a mistake in your title.

Comment: What is a "closed" function ? And which "those" points ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange the equation as $\displaystyle y^2+\frac{1}{2}(x^4+2x^2)=2c^2$.

Add $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$ to each side of the equation.

$\displaystyle y^2+\frac{1}{2}(x^4+2x^2+1)=2c^2+\frac{1}{2}$.

$\displaystyle y^2+\frac{1}{2}(x^2+1)^2=2c^2+\frac{1}{2}$.

Finally, multiply by $2$ to get $2y^2+(x^2+1)^2=4c^2+1$.

Notice that as long as $|c|>0$, for every $x$, such that $|x|<\sqrt{\sqrt{4c^2+1}-1} $ there are exactly $2$ sufficient $y$, except $1$ at equality.

The curve is, thus, closed.

Comment: Thanks a million, This helped